# Are the EU authorities asking the Ukrainians to sell out the occupied regions?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, ukraine

The EU president has officially [started](https://www.euronews.com/2022/04/08/von-der-leyen-gives-ukraine-questionnaire-for-eu-accession-discussions) the process to admit Ukraine into the EU. At the same time the [NATO membership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93NATO_relations) discussions are going on. Trouble is that to enter such groups Ukraine must solve the open conflict, this mean that they may be force to accept the status quo which currently see the Russian Federation in an advantageous position.

Therefore announcing the start of the process before the peace talks will give the Russians an additional leverage, why such bad timing?

Comment: You are assuming that "announcing the start of the process before the peace talks will give the Russians an additional leverage" and therefore that this is "bad timing". I suggest you reword that last sentence.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Ukrainians want to be member of NATO and/or EU, so it's kind of the other way around. On the other hand the value of a membership for this conflict is already quite low. One can only guess how history would have developed if NATO would have accepted Ukraine before 2014. But that is largely academic. So far, nobody is really selling out occupied regions although I guess that Russia will hold a few more of their infamous "we want to be part of Russia" referenda.

Answer (score 4):

> announcing the start of the process before the peace talks will give the Russians an additional leverage, why such bad timing?

This is basically a bad premise predicating the question. It's not clear to me that Russia gets any advantage whatsoever from the Ukraine-EU accession talks.

It's worth recalling that:

- Turkey has been in such talks with the EU [for decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accession_of_Turkey_to_the_European_Union).
- Serbia is [supposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accession_of_Serbia_to_the_European_Union) to join by 2025. I'm not holding my breath given that they're another country beholden to Russian gas and cultural influences. And yeah, Kosovo [supposedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accession_of_Kosovo_to_the_European_Union) might join on the same date. Which would basically require Serbia to "normalize relations" with the latter, which to me reads like quasi-recognition.
- West Germany was admitted as a founding member even though it had not given up claims to East Germany, or even accepted the Oder-Neisse line (with Poland) etc. (Granted, the chance of peaceful reunification with Russian-majority regions are much lower than it was between the two Germanies.)

Comment: Another relevant example is the admission of Cyprus into the EU, while there is an ongoing occupation of territory by Turkey. Nobody needed to recognize the occupation as lawful for the integration of the free territory to happen.

Answer (score 2):

The EU and NATO member states have **given themselves** guidelines on preconditions for admission. They are clarifications for prospective members and the public on what the process is. Yet every single case will be an **individual decision**. If the EU27 want to admit Ukraine tomorrow, while the war is going on, they can do it. It would commit them to declare war on Russia, however.

(Well, some members have said that future expansions would require treaty changes which require a plebiscite, but that is a *domestic* decision and a sufficient majority in those members could change that. For instance, many believe that before there is *any* enlargement, the unanimity requirements must be relaxed. And the number of commissioners should not be tied to the number of member states. Etc.)

But normally, the process of EU admission takes many years. Starting it now is a political signal, and a chance to get some of the paperwork out of the way. I may be surprised by the speed of future events, but I don't expect full membership anytime this decade.

Comment: My question is about the timing of the announcement that is being given to the Ukrainian citizens, not the timing of the end of the process.

Comment: @FluidCode, do you suggest they should have rejected the Ukrainian accession request for now? NATO did.

Comment: "do you suggest?" My question is "why such bad timing?", please do not add other opinions.

Comment: @FluidCode, you appear to insist to use *your* interpretation of the effects as the only basis for valid answers.

Comment: @FluidCode Your use of **why such bad timing?** makes your question a loaded question, and most likely a bad faith question. The only acceptable answer (to you) is one that says that the timing was indeed bad.

Comment: To add to it that the EU, since it is responsible only to itself for its own rules, could decide, in this case, to extend security guarantees to Ukraine *while it is not yet in the EU*.  In fact, if a negotiated settlement has Russia "OK-ing" EU membership in return for something, I'd expect the EU to put in the guarantees *first*, rather than rushing the admittance process overall (Ukraine had a fair bit of corruption to clean up IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that Ukraine's government sees its **prospective membership of the EU**<sup>*</sup> as something that Russia doesn't want, and therefore **may be brought to the negotiating table** (and potentially bargained away in return for greater concessions from Russia)?

If so, doesn't it put Ukraine in a better position, and is therefore a strength rather than a weakness? And isn't asking for it now, before negotiations have been concluded, *good* timing for Ukraine, not bad?

<sup>(* The same would also apply to NATO membership *if* that were a realistic prospect before the war and borders were settled.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that a Nato membership would first require peace, but asfaik this does not apply to an EU membership. Since the later is much more probable to happen (even if not tomorrow), I don't think that's really bad timing with respect to a possible EU membership.

The Ukrainian government obviously wants to show their people that they're going to orient themselves towards the EU and the west, just what the Russians allegedly wanted to prevent with the invasion.

Comment: EU membership also comes with security guarantees. If Ukraine joined the EU today, the EU members would be approximately as compelled to declare war on Russia as the NATO members would be if Ukraine joins NATO. The big difference, the US and UK would not be on the list.